# getting UIImage filename loaded from xib

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow intercept the loading process of an image from a xib file. In light of iPhone 5 aspect ratio, it would be useful to redirect the loading of an image from a xib file, making it to load another image (with the 568h name). 
I was thinking of using categories. I already have the category for [UIImage imageNamed:] but it doesn't work with xib files. The initWithCoder from the UIView, inherited by UIImageView would be a good place to start, but at this point I don't have the imageName, as it was read from the xib file. 
Any ideas as to how this might be accomplished?
Thanks!

Comment: I never found a solution for this.. Up so far.. I think there is no reliable way to do it.

Comment: +1, I'm searching for the same.